# RxJS Subscribing different Observables inside subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using angular with ngrx store and RxJS to store and transform some personal portfolios and the appropriate quotes. When a new quote comes in, the calculations, which are done by a web worker, should trigger. Initially, I used this code to achieve the desired effect, but I noticed some flaws.

```
this.subs.sink = combineLatest([this.portfolio$, this.transactions$])
  .pipe(sample(this.triggerCalculation$))
  .subscribe(([portfolio, transactions]) => {
    if (!portfolio || !transactions || transactions.length === 0) {
      return
    }

    this.worker.postMessage({ message: 'calculate positions', payload: { portfolio, transactions } })

    this.subs.sink = combineLatest([
      this.store.select((s) => s.performance.positionMembers),
      this.store.select((s) => s.quotes.currencies),
    ]).subscribe(([positionMembers, currencies]) => {
      if (positionMembers.length === 0 || currencies === {}) {
        return
      }

      if (portfolio?.watchlist && positionMembers) {
        this.worker.postMessage({
          message: 'calculate total on static change'
        })

        portfolio.watchlist.all.forEach((a) => {
          if (positionMembers.includes(a._id)) {
            this.subs.sink = this.store
              .select((s) => s.quotes.quotes[a._id])
              .subscribe((q) => {
                if (q?.price) {
                  this.worker.postMessage({
                    message: 'calculate performance',
                    payload: {
                      id: a._id,
                      quote: q,
                      currency: a.currency,
                      currencies,
                      baseCurrency: portfolio.baseCurrency,
                    },
                  })
                }
              })
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

I already refactored this to be way better, at least I think so. I also improved some of the filtering:

```
this.subs.sink = this.transactions$
  .pipe(
    sample(this.triggerCalculation$),
    withLatestFrom(this.portfolio$),
    filter(([transactions, portfolio]) => portfolio?.watchlist && transactions?.length !== 0),
    tap(([transactions, portfolio]) => {
      this.worker.postMessage({ message: 'calculate positions', payload: { portfolio, transactions } })
    }),
    switchMap(([, portfolio]) => {
      return combineLatest([
        this.store.select((s) => s.performance.positionMembers),
        this.store.select((s) => s.quotes.currencies),
        of(portfolio),
      ]).pipe(filter(([members, currencies]) => !!members?.length && Object.keys(currencies).length !== 0))
    }),
    tap(() => {
      this.worker.postMessage({
        message: 'calculate total on static change',
      })
    })
  )
  .subscribe(([members, currencies, portfolio]) => {
    portfolio.watchlist.all.forEach((a) => {
      if (members.includes(a._id)) {
        this.subs.sink = this.store
          .select((s) => s.quotes.quotes[a._id])
          .pipe(filter((q) => !!q?.price))
          .subscribe((q) => {
            console.warn('subscription')
            this.worker.postMessage({
              message: 'calculate performance',
              payload: {
                id: a._id,
                quote: q,
                currency: a.currency,
                currencies,
                baseCurrency: portfolio.baseCurrency,
              },
            })
          })
      }
    })
  })
```

My final question is how to get rid of the inner subscription (last block with `portfolio.watchlist.all.forEach`), where I create multiple subscriptions. The goal is to have as many subscriptions as quotes. I also change the whole object everytime new quotes are received, so subscribing the whole object would trigger even more often. Note that the subscriptions are created everytime the outer subscription triggers, so there might be an infinite number of inner subscriptions which exactly do the same. I only need them to be created once, but they should also reflect new quotes leading to new subscriptions.

If some experienced RxJS programmers could help me, I'd be really glad.

Comment: I have never found a valid scenario where a subscribe inside another subscribe is a valid approach.
Whenever you have a scenario where you feel that you need a subscribe inside another, check the Higher Order Observables (like mergeMap, switchMap, etc).

Take a look at this article here: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/